# laravel vue.js The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I am creating commenting system. Now, I want to post a new comment, but when I send a comment, I got an error in http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments/51.

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
>   POST.

I want to post a comment in this URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/results/51.

In my chrome dev tool console, I have this error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

`web.php`

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){
    //post a comment
    Route::POST('comments/{post}', 'CommentController@store')->name('comment.store');
});


//comment area
Route::get('results/{post}/comments', 'CommentController@index');
Route::get('comments/{comment}/replies', 'CommentController@show');
```

`comments.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="commentarea" > 
    <div class="comment-posts" >
        <div v-if="!auth" class="user-comment-area" >
            <div  class="user-post">
                <!---<img src="{{asset('people/person7.jpg')}}" class="image-preview__image">--->
                <input v-model="newComment" type="text" name="comment">
            </div>
            <div class="comments-buttons">
                <button class="cancel-button">Cancel</button>
                <button @click="addComment" class="comment-button" type="submit">Comment</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h4>Comments ()</h4>

        <div class="reply-comment"  v-for="comment in comments.data" :key="comment.id">
                <div class="user-comment">
                <div class="user">
                    <!---<img src="{{ $comment->user->img }}" class="image-preview__image">--->
                    <avatar :username="comment.user.name"></avatar>
                </div>
                <div class="user-name">
                    <span class="comment-name"><a href="">{{ comment.user.name }}</a></span>
                    <p>{{ comment.body }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="reply">
                <button class="reply-button">
                    <i class="fas fa-reply"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
                <replies :comment="comment"></replies>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button v-if="comments.next_page_url" @click="fetchComments" class="load">Load More</button>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Avatar from 'vue-avatar'
import Replies from './replies.vue'
export default {
    props: ['post'],
    components: {
        Avatar,
        Replies
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchComments()
    },
    data: () => ({
        comments: {
            data: []
        },
        newComment: '',
        auth: ''
    }),
    methods: {
        fetchComments() {
            const url = this.comments.next_page_url ? this.comments.next_page_url : `/results/${this.post.id}/comments`

            axios.get(url).then(({ data }) => {
                this.comments = {
                    ...data,
                    data: [
                        ...this.comments.data,
                        ...data.data
                    ]
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error.response);
            })
        },
        addComment() {
            if(! this.newComment) return
            axios.post(`/comments/${this.post.id}`, {
                body: this.newComment
            }).then(( {data} ) => {
                this.comments = {
                    ...this.comments,
                    data: [
                        data,
                        ...this.comments.data
                    ]
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

`commentsController.php`

```
public function store(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    return auth()->user()->comments()->create([
        'body' => $request->body,
        'post_id' => $post->id,
        'comment_id' => $request->comment_id
    ])->fresh();
}
```

`comment.php`

```
protected $appends = ['repliesCount'];

public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}

public function getRepliesCountAttribute()
{
    return $this->replies->count();
}
```

I am glad if someone helps me out.

Comment: Not entirely sure but if you make an axios post request like this, shouldn't you be sending some Authorization header as well? Since the post route is behind the Auth middleware, so otherwise it will check for other routes that match '/comments/'

Comment: Yes, exactly you are right. After I solve the issue, I removed auth check from my vue file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

your URL is :  http://127.0.0.1:8000/results/51.

your routes should be :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'],function () {
    Route::post('comments/{post_id}', 'CommentController@store')->name('comment.store');
});
```

your controller will be :

```
public function store(Request $request,$post_id)
{
    return auth()->user()->comments()->create([
        'body' => $request->body,
        'post_id' => $post_id,
        'comment_id' => $request->comment_id
    ])->fresh();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I put catch method, and the issue was I forgot putting protected $fillable ['body','post_id', 'comment_id']. It is a silly mistake.

Comment: Thank you, but as I posted above, I cold find a solution. thank you very much for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I put catch method, and the issue was I did not include protected $fillable ['body','post_id', 'comment_id'] in comment model.